# Удостоивать и удостаивать

Tags: орфография

Удостоивать или удостаивать? Какая из этих форм более пригодна к использованию? У Достоевского встречаю вариант через "о".

Answer (score 2):

В современном языке правильно *"удост**а**ивать". "Удост**о**ивать"* — это устаревший вариант, для Достоевского вполне подходящий (см. [здесь](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/9345)).

Answer (score 2):

Обе пригодны. Но современный вариант - удостАивать.

Вообще чередование О и А как дополнительный способ выражения вида глагола не нов, он восходит к древнейшим временам, когда и самой категории вида в языке не было, но было чередование О и А, доставшееся от праиндоевропейского - взамен существовавшего там разделения гласных на долгие и краткие.

Это тенденция потеряла продуктивность на ранних стадия развития собственно русского языка, но в последние век-полтора снова набрала силу.
Ср. ***взбодрить-взбадривать, оспорить-оспаривать*** (при том, что еще у Пушкина регулярно "оспоривать"), ***высосать-высасывать*** и другие.
Кроме того, существуют и относительно равноправные формы (***растаможивать*** и ***растамаживать***).
Впрочем, есть и обратные примеры. ***Откупаривать*** (старая норма) - ***откупоривать*** (современная).

Вместе с тем наблюдаются подобные чередования в имперфективах не только для А и О, но и для некоторых других пар гласных.
Подробнее [тут](http://%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F.%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3/w/index.php?title=%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85).

Comment: А где можно убедиться, что было *откуп**а**ривать?* Нашёл онлайн-словарь Даля — там О: https://gufo.me/dict/dal/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой http://www.klf.kpfu.ru/russlovar18-19/sar-1/dict_db/words.php?letter=%CE&kind=2&sort=1&&page=83  Это минимум за век до Даля.

Comment: Спасибо, любопытно!

Comment: Наверное, всё-таки не _растомаживать_, а _растамаживать_. Таможня же, а не томожня.